# How can i change the size that my QTableWidget gets printed?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've written a program which gets input and inserts images in qtablewidget cells according to the input. I have a print button which opens a print dialog(that works) and prints the table using QPainter.

My problem is that the table is printed at a smaller scale(you can’t  understand much from it). How can i resize my print?

```
from RD2 import Ui_RD
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QImage, QPen, QColor, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter

class ImgWidget1(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self,parameters, parent=None):
        super(ImgWidget1, self).__init__(parent)
        #print(self.parent.a.text())
        self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath1)
        self.setPixmap(self.pic)
        self.parameters = parameters

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QColor('red'))
        #painter.begin(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pic)
        A, B, C, D = self.parameters
        painter.drawText(150,13, str(A))
        painter.drawText(16,35, str(B))
        painter.drawText(150,55, str(C))
        painter.drawText(272,35, str(D))
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.ui = Ui_RD()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.printButton.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        self.ui.addButton.clicked.connect(self.adauga)

        self.nr_row = 0


    def adauga(self):
        A = self.ui.a.text()
        B = self.ui.b.text()
        C = self.ui.c.text()
        D = self.ui.d.text()

        self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount())

        if int(A) != 0 and int(B) != 0 and int(C) != 0 and int(D) != 0:
            widget1 = ImgWidget1((A,B,C,D))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.nr_row, 3, widget1)

    def handlePrint(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
            self.handlePaintRequest(printer)

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        self.ui.tableWidget.render(painter)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = Main()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Is the size an issue for actual paper printing or pdf? Btw, if you share code that requires an external resource (the `.ui` file created with Designer) you should provide that too, otherwise (usually better) make a self contained example that creates the GUI by itself.

Comment: Actual paper prinring

Comment: Then it might depend on the DPI of the printer. Have you tried to use [`setResolution()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setResolution)?

Comment: @musicamante no, How do i do that?